# FTP Image displaying issue on wordpress site

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have uploaded an image folder in my child theme on `wordpress-images->homeimages->myimage.jpg`. When i go to `mywebsiteexample.com/images/homeimages/myimage.jpg`, it returns that page is not available and as a result i cannot use relative path in img src to call the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do this way as like

```
mywebsiteexample.com/wp-content/themes/themefoldername/images/homeimages/myimage.jpg
```

For example 
Use this
  to get the current active theme directory

you can call something like to load the image

```
<img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/homeimages/myimage.jpg"/>
```

Hope it may help

Comment: thanks "websiteexample.com/wp-content/themes/themefoldername/images/homeimages/myimage.jpg" but this returns page cannot be found as well

Comment: what your theme name? you could replace themefoldername to your theme name

Comment: Thanks got it..the reason it was not working was i was including plulic html in the url "mydomainc.com/public_html/wp-content/.."

Comment: I think you could use the second one, because if you want to load multiple images then it hard also if you are change the domain also it hard to load all those file path again use bloginfo instead of hardcode one by one

Comment: yes thanks and using
   <?php echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?  >/images/homeimages/myimage.jpg"/>

actuall calls the images from the child theme directory rather than the parent theme directory